# linq where with container type

Tags: linq

I have a repository method like,

```
  public List<Township> lst(string multipletownship)
    {
        var foo = from x in db.Townships
                  select new { x.TownshipID, x.JTownshipName };
        string[] sarr;
        if (multipletownship.Contains(','))
        {
            sarr = multipletownship.Split(',');

            foo = foo.Where(s => s.TownshipID == sarr[0] || s.TownshipID==sarr[1]);
        }
        else
        {
            foo = foo.Where(s => s.TownshipID == multipletownship);
        }
```

multipletownship parameter value is `1,2`.These are township id.The question is how can i filter townshipid to multiple at the `if condition`.It that possible or I have to do with some loop...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no `,` in multipletownship string, then you will get an array with single item:

```
public List<Township> lst(string multipletownship)
{
    string[] sarr = multipletownship.Split(',');
    var foo = from x in db.Townships
              where sarr.Contains(x.TownshipID)
              select new { x.TownshipID, x.JTownshipName };

    // return
}
```

Comment: @KhinThuThuMon I updated answer (I think you can put where clause in your main query)